# get difference from three arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the difference between three arrays

`array_diff()` function doesn't help because it matches only the first array with others

For example I want to compare three arrays and each array has one of the element different from each other like this

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue", 'v1' => 'sss');
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue", 'v2' => 'ss');
$a3=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue", 'v3' => 's');
```

when I use `array_diff()` on these arrays it would just show me the unique value out of other two arrays

```
$res = array_diff($a1, $a2, $a3);

print_r($res);
```

It's result would be `Array ( [v1] => sss )`

While I want it to tell me the unique values in all these arrays like this `Array ( [v1] => sss [v2] => ss [v3] => s )`

I tried other array comparison functions but couldn't find one to compare all given array to each other instead of comparing just one array to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $var=(array_diff($a1,$a2,$a3));
    $var1=(array_diff($a2,$a1,$a3));
    $var2=(array_diff($a3,$a2,$a1));
    $v=array_merge($var,$var1,$var2);
```

I guess this helps for you.check it out..